# TypeError $(...).meanmenu not a function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Its been about hours that I am trying to figuringout what is the mistaking that I am missing here...

Can anyone help me to find where I am getting wrong..Sorry I am new to Jquery..

Main.js

```
  (function($) {
    'use strict';
    
    $('.mobile-menu nav').meanmenu({
        meanMenuContainer: '.mobile-menu-area',
        meanScreenWidth: "991",
        meanRevealPosition: "right",
    });
  })(jQuery);
```

Error in console:

[image: here]

complete main.js :
https://jsfiddle.net/75w20s36/

Complete meanmenu.js
https://jsfiddle.net/v9zhy38m/

Comment: have you loaded the meanmenu plugin..?

Comment: What is the source of the `meanmenu` plugin?

Comment: Did you load it after the jquery library and is the code you wrote loaded after that? It has to be loaded in that order in order for it to work, jQuery->meanmenu->your code

Comment: Either you aren't loading meanmenu or you're overwriting jQuery after loading it … but your question is missing a [mcve].

Comment: @codelone — Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed.

Comment: @codelone — The complete main.js is neither minimal (seriously, it is huge!) nor complete (it doesn't show how you are loading jQuery, or the plugin).

Comment: Your main.js file does not have any function named `meanmenu` this is not a native function of jQuery. And it looks like the library with this function is missing in your code.

Comment: The jsfiddle provided is just OPs main.js - it's not a working example showing all of the includes *in the correct order* so does nothing more to demonstrate the problem than the snippet already in the question.

Comment: @codelone show your html `<script>` tags where you include jquery, meanmenu and then your main.js.  Also include any errors you have before the one in your screenshot.

Comment: Re edit: Stop linking to a third-party website to show huge amounts of code. Do, as you've been told at least twice already, provide the HTML you are using to load the scripts. Provide a [mcve] **in the question itself**.

Comment: I am on my mobile and posting this question only..sory for that.

Comment: Thankyou so much for helping me out....I thing I am new that is why I am not go through perameters well. Please upvote to delete this question...I have found a solution...thankyou.

Comment: You should be able to delete the question without it having upvotes. SO encourages the deletion of bad questions without good answers. (The upvotes on Steven's answer might block deletion though).

Comment: So, What instead what would I do now? Should I left it as well..?

Comment: Glad you found your solution - but this question as it stands won't help anyone in the future; you should be able to delete the question without accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you show a complete version of it?
it is possible the the main.js are loaded first. or you can ensure it is working by attach it only when document ready. like follow:

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';
    
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('.mobile-menu nav').meanmenu({ 
            meanMenuContainer: '.mobile-menu-area', 
            meanScreenWidth: "991", 
            meanRevealPosition: "right"
        }); 
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Not my downvote as I prefer to make suggestions to new users:  Your code essentially says "it works for me" or is at best a comment requesting a [mcve] (`[mcve]` in comments).  Wrapping in doc.ready doesn't provide an answer to `is not a function` as if the selector doesn't exist, they'll still get the same error.  It *is possible* this would fix if OP did:  jquery.js - this code - meanmean.js.

Comment: i point out that it is possible that the main.js are loaded first, before the plugin meanmenu are loaded. thus i suppose ensure it to execute after dom are ready would be solve it, since the plugin would also be loaded at that time.

Comment: I'm just advising a possible reason for the downvote

Comment: Also note that SO is entirely fickle!  People often downvote answers to bad questions (which they shouldn't) as they feel the question shouldn't be answered as it's a bad question (but don't provide any feedback to show this)

Comment: @codelone — Did it solve the problem? Is it useful? The tooltips for up and down votes on answers indicate that votes should be for usefulness, not effort. People can put effort into producing a bad answer and it does a disservice to other people who come along looking for answers and find bad ones with positive ratings. This answer is highly speculative (I can think of at least three different explanations for the problem, but can't narrow it down due to the lack of a [mcve], and this answer only addresses one of them … and even then in a suboptimal way).

Comment: Next time I will upvote only those answers which will help other people as well in future thankyou so much @Quentin for guidance..